# Asymptotic behaviour of $W_{-1}(c)$ , for $c\rightarrow 0-0$?

Tags: calculus, lambert-w, branch-cuts

If we solve the equation $x\cdot e^x=c$ with $-\frac{1}{e}< c<0$ , we get two solutions, namely $productlog(0,c)$ and $productlog(-1,c)$ , sometimes written as $W_0(c)$ and $W_{-1}(c)$. $W_{-1}(c)$ gives the solution with $x<-1$

> If $c$ tends to $0$, what is the asymptotic formula for $W_{-1}(c)$ ?

I couldn't get an answer with Wolfram Alpha.

Motivation : If $c$ is negative, but very near $0$, I would like to have a good start-value for the Newton-method for the solution smaller than $-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $z=0$ the all branches $W_k$ have a similar expansion, see [1](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/%7Edjeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf) formula 4.22:
$$W_k(z) = \ln z + 2\pi i k - \ln( \ln z + 2\pi i k) + \cdots.$$

In [1](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/%7Edjeffrey/Offprints/W-adv-cm.pdf) there is section 5 on numerical computation where they suggest Halley's method.

For pure real computation see
D. Veberic, Having Fun with Lambert W(x) Function,
http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1628:

$$W_{−1}(x) = \ln(−x)−\ln(−(\ln(−x)− \ln(−(\ln(− x ) − ... )))) $$